# Installing dependencies for a python code in windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10, libraries, apt-get, chocolatey

There is a python script that I want to run on windows 10 but it requires these dependencies:

> apt-get install python-dmidecode libcdio-utils acpidump mesa-utils

But windows does not support the "apt-get" command.

I have tried chocolatey but I couldn't find those libraries that I am trying to download.

Anyone have any ideas on how I could make that script work?

Comment: why you are running Linux command apt-get on window box.
Please install pip or set-up script for window and try to install all the module with pip command,
python -m pip install <module-Name>

Comment: you will never install `mesa-utils` on windows ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use "pip"(version 2 or 3) or "easy_install"(version 2 or 3) in :

```
C:\"Your Python version"\Scripts>
```

or

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\"Your Pythonn Version"\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is package distribution manager for Ubuntu and a few other linux distributions.  It only handles linux packages, so there is no point trying to get it running on Windows 10.

For handling / managing Python packages and dependencies, you can try using Conda.  You can install it by downloading either Anaconda or Miniconda.  After installation, to get a new package use either

```
conda install <packagename>
```

or

```
pip install <packagename>
```

as Anaconda/Miniconda installs pip as well.

Comment: except the apt-get stuff he is trying to install is not at all python (w the exception of the first one) ... and there is no equivalent of mesa-utils for windows that i know of ...

Comment: I have installed Anaconda but the packages I searched for are not there. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Conda is a binary installation tool.  It handles more than just python libraries.  Liron: you need to list what packages you are trying to install